# Saving a model in Django gives me "Warning: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value"

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a very basic model in Django:

```
class Case(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def save(self):
        if self.created_at == None:
             self.created_at = datetime.now()
        self.updated_at = datetime.now()
        super(Case, self).save()

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'cases'
```

Because I did not specify the PK, Django took care of that for me.   I see the field in my database which is called "id", marked as a primary key and auto-increment. I find odd to be getting that warning since everything is cool on the DB and model end.  The error is:

```
_mysql_exceptions.Warning

Warning: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

My work around when saving is to set the id to 0.  It kills the warning and the id gets set properly anyway since MySQL handles it.

```
case = Case()
case.id = 0 #ugly workaround for - Warning: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
case.name = request.POST[u'case[name]']
case.save()
```

The issue with this solution is:

1. It's ugly
2. The new PK is inaccessible after saving which makes it
   impossible to serialize properly

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I'm running:

```
Python 2.7.2
django.VERSION (1, 3, 1, 'final', 0)
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.45, for apple-darwin10.2.0 (i386) using readline 5.1
MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg
```

And my create table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `cases` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=45 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: What versions of everything are you using?  Python, django, mysql, mysql driver?  Also, can you post the results of mysql "show create table yourappname_cases;"?

Comment: Good idea.  Details added to the question

Answer (score 15):

I'd like to expand on this question as I've ran into it this week. I was getting this same exact error and taking a look at the model definition and SQL definition showed that:

1. The models affected either had no PK explicitly defined or had a PK explicitly defined (both had problems). This alone seemed unrelated.
2. The tables affected had the "id" definition as in the OP, i.e. `id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`. The `PRIMARY KEY` is set as expected.
3. Looking into the MySQL query log I got something to this extent:

   ```
   INSERT INTO `x` (...) VALUES (...)
   SHOW WARNINGS
   ROLLBACK
   ```

   Running the query individually is successful, and `SHOW WARNINGS` reflects the warning noted in the OP.

I however came across a MySQL-end fix, http://webit.ca/2012/01/field-id-doesnt-have-a-default-value/ mentioned that resetting the id definition (which at a cursory glance appears to not be any different) fixes the problem. I can't explain why this works, but it addresses the problem without any additional code changes. I believe this may be in some way linked to removing records, but the whole issue seems non-sensical to me.

Comment: +1 thanks, like OP I was wondering if table def is correct in mysql why there is error, but this clarifies it, a bug in mysql has any one filed ticket?

Comment: I encountered this issue using Django/South after migrating a column to an Autofield with MySQL. Apparently this warning is a side effect of the migration and the MySQL-end fix you suggest solves the issue. There's a South ticket here for more info: http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/1160

Comment: Just in case the link ever goes down, here is the command to run on the table you are having problems with: `ALTER TABLE problem_table MODIFY \`id\` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;`

Answer (score 5):

Do you have a chance to recreate the database? It seems there might be something wrong with it.

As a side note: You don't have to call `datetime.now()` for `created_at` if you already set the default of field to be `datetime.now`.

Comment: What could be wrong with my database?  The attributes on the PK look exactly the same as the attributes on Django generated tables' PKs

Answer (score 2):

Your save method is really not necessary, you can use the arguments: `DateField.auto_now` and `DateField.auto_now_add`. Those arguments handle your created_at and updated_at attributes:

1. `DateField.auto_now`: Automatically set the field to now every time the object is saved. Useful for "last-modified" timestamps.
2. `DateField.auto_now_add`: Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps.

Try again just using the default save() method, hope it helps!

More info about `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield

Comment: Ok, so definitely the error is not in the `save()` method. Have to be something wrong with the database. Are you using South or something like that?

Comment: Yes I am using South, but again the database looks fine and the model definition looks fine.  The only thing in between them is the Python mysql driver right?  That is where I see the warning getting thrown

Comment: I have a lot of bad experiences with the South app, I bet it has something to do with it. Sometimes is useful to drop the table, create it yourself using the `manage.py sqlall [appname]` SQL generated code and run a fake migration `migrate [appname] [number_of_change] --fake`.

Comment: OK I'll give that a shot.  Do I have to tell all my other developers to do the same?  Also do you have any recommendations for managing migrations?  Sorry it's day 3 on Django for me and I'm missing some Rails features ...like migrations...

Comment: well, it's really not so recommended to do it. I suggested because it worked for me several times, but maybe is not the best thing to do if you don't have much experience in Django or South. Here goes an important question: has this database ever worked? I mean, was it working fine before the error?

Answer (score 1):

save method sometimes uses additional arguments and keywors arguments but you dont handle them.
I'm not sure but this may fix your problem

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.created_at == None:
         self.created_at = datetime.now()
    self.updated_at = datetime.now()
    super(Case, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Im sure youve probably fixed the issue by now, but I just ran into the same problem.

Turns out auto-increment wasnt set for the primary key, so I fixed the issue by turning auto-increment on for each primary key in my database.

Hope that helps anyone else who gets the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by filtering out the warning:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value")
```

Now the saving and serialization looks good

Comment: Doesn't seem like the right solution.  Nobody else is getting that warning.

Comment: it's a pretty desperate solution

Comment: This is wrong, see answer by @Aea , it seems to be problem at mysql end

Comment: This is not a solution, you are just ignoring a warning message

Answer (score 0):

I have too the same problem, when I look into the mysql structure the field 'id' is not the first field. I changed the structure such a way that it will apperar as first field, then my issue is solved. But I still unknown the real problem behind it.

SQL script before the problem solved for that table:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `marketing_sponseredhashtag` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2013-02-12 14:00:04',
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2013-02-12 14:00:04',
  `payment` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `paid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `expiry_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  **`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,**
  `tag` varchar(180) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `marketing_sponseredhashtag_403f60f` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

After issue fixed the structure:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `marketing_sponseredhashtag` (
  **`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,**
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2013-02-12 14:00:04',
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2013-02-12 14:00:04',
  `payment` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `paid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `expiry_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(180) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `marketing_sponseredhashtag_403f60f` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

Answer (score 0):

I had same error when running migrations and it turned out that I had to change the structure of the default django tables : *django_admin_log*, *django_content_type* and *django_migrations* since **the primary key wasn't set correctly** (I don't know why, maybe a bad migration at some point)

I used the following query to update the tables :

```sql
ALTER TABLE django_migrations MODIFY id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```